# How Do I Add A Status Message to a Reset Password Redirect? (Laravel 5.6)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to find a way to add a status message to the default ResetPasswordController redirect, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've tried replacing the default

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

with

```
public function redirectTo() {
  return redirect()->home()->with('status', 'Your password has been changed successfully!');
}
```

but I was met with an error. I've read on other posts that the default adds a status message already, but I have an area to show the status and nothing pops up. (Any other status the project has, it shows fine)

```
@if (session('status'))
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
  </div>
@endif
```

I haven't found any helpful information on this in the documentation either, has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: What is not working? What error? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: On the redirect it just loads the homepage with no sort of indication that the password change was successful. A status message is supposed to be included, but no message at all appears.

Comment: How do you do the redirect? Where is the code that call the `redirectTo()` function?

Comment: Try with `return redirect("/home")->with(...)` instead of `return redirect()->home()->with(...)`

Comment: @TimLewis after doing that change I'm getting an error message of "Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected".

Comment: Huh, that's a new one... I was wondering if `redirect()->home()` was performing 2 redirects, which might null out the message on the second one.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help.

```
public function redirectTo() {
 Session::flash('status', 'Your password has been changed successfully!');
  return redirect('home');
}
```

Dont forget to use Session class at top.

Comment: I tried this and was given the error "Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected". Any ideas?